# Метка [pagespeed-insights] — синонимизировать или удалить?

Tags: предложение, метки, синонимы-меток, удаление-метки, переименование-метки

В процессе сжигания метки [google](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google) наткнулся на метку [pagespeed-insights](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pagespeed-insights), по сервису Гугла *Google PageSpeed Insights*. В то же время недавно создали метку [google-pagespeed](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-pagespeed). По правилам ресурса полагается в название метки по сервису какого-то сайта добавлять название этого сайта. То есть метка [pagespeed-insights](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pagespeed-insights) — неправильная. Однако в ней целых 63 вопроса — удалять как-то долго (хотя по сравнению с гуглом, конечно, вообще ни о чем).

Есть два способа решения проблемы с этой меткой:

- Все-таки снести ее, не так уж и долго.
- Синонимизировать с [google-pagespeed](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-pagespeed).

**P.S.** В процессе обнаружил, что существует еще и метка [pagespeed](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pagespeed), на 12 вопросов. С ней тоже надо разбираться, мучаться с синонимизацией или просто снести (могут создать обратно).

Comment: Кстати, подобная же ситуация и с [protobuf] — [google-protobuf].

Comment: protobuf'ы объединил

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если текущее название метки неподходящее, то существует процедура переименования  метки (когда новое имя ещё не используется). Это может сделать модератор.

[pagespeed](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pagespeed) можно легко синонимизировать к новой (правильной) метке, если есть достаточные подтверждения того, что здесь не будет неоднозначностей в использовании метки.

С меткой [google-pagespeed](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-pagespeed), как я вижу, пока вопросов никаких нет. Удалять полезные метки точно не стоит.

Comment: [tag:google-page-speed] думаю имелось в виду. Там всего 4 вопроса, можно вручную выпилить.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight, так эту метку и надо оставить. Она же с названием сервиса.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight на enso [что-то много](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yoXbV.jpg), и без синонимов.

Comment: [google-page-speed] создана недавно и она неоднозначна между mod pagespeed и PageSpeed Insights. По мне надо ее сносить и переносить эти 4 вопроса в [pagespeed-insights]. Но сам я в этих сервисах не разбираюсь, поэтому сильных предпочтений у меня нет.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight как я понимаю, mod_pagespeed вообще к гуглу отношения не имеет, т.е. неоднозначность есть, когда просто "pagespeed". Об этом как раз на [meta.EnSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/361834/3240681) говорят.

Comment: @Глеб обрати внимание ^